# Java Stream - only modify string

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map` object which contains a mixture of integers, floats and strings. I would like to use the Java `Stream API` to operate ONLY on key/value strings and trim the white space, returning a new object which returns the string k/v pairs with removed whitespace and the original integer/floats should be retained.

Example:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("number1     ", 1323);
        map.put("string1     ", "   chicken      ");
        map.put("number2", 11.1307907792);
        map.put("string2", "21 ");
```

Transformed to:

```
"number1" -> 1323 (type int)
"string1" -> "chicken" (type string)
"number2" -> 11.1307907792 (type float)
"string2" -> "21" (type string)
```

I have tried the following however it does not discriminate between the objects type:

```java
Map<String, Object> trimmed = map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().trim(),
                        e -> e.getValue().toString().trim()));
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, `HashMap` does not have any order.

Comment: @LorisSecuro thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the value is an instance of string before you convert it.

```
Map<String, Object> trimmed = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().trim(),
                    e -> (e.getValue() instanceof String ? ((String) e.getValue()).trim() : e.getValue())));
```

though you might want to make this a little clearer by introducing a helper method:

```
static Object trimIfString(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        return ((String) value).trim();
    }
    return value;
}

...

Map<String, Object> trimmed = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().trim(),
                     e -> trimIfString(e.getValue())));
```